# Convert decimal? to double?

Tags: c#, nullable

I am wondering what would be the best way (in the sense of safer and succinct) to convert from one nullable type to another "compatible" nullable type.

Specifically, converting from decimal? to double? can be done using:

```
public double? ConvertToNullableDouble(decimal? source)
{
    return source.HasValue ? Convert.ToDouble(source) : (double?) null;
}
```

Is there any better way to do this? Maybe leveraging a standard conversion?

Comment: Your way is a good way.

Comment: You are doing it right! Check also this reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487685/conversion-between-nullable-types

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Built in casts for the win! Just tested this in VS2012 *and* VS2010:

```
 decimal? numberDecimal = new Decimal(5); 
 decimal? nullDecimal = null;
 double? numberDouble = (double?)numberDecimal; // = 5.0
 double? nullDouble = (double?)nullDecimal;     // = null
```

Just using an explicit cast will cast null to null, and the internal decimal value to double. Success!

Comment: Tested it and works like a charm. Thanks, this was what I was looking for but I didn't think of a built in cast.

Comment: It's strange, since in questions like the one MUG4N linked to it seems a lot of people have theories, but no-one actually *tried*. :)

Comment: In fact *all* conversions that involve a non-nullable value type source and target may be "lifted to nullable".

Comment: @EricLippert That's strange, since I could see an *explicit* conversion to the non-nullable type, but not an implicit one.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: The conversion from decimal to double is explicit, so the conversion from decimal? to double? is also.

Comment: Just as information: it works based on my experience in the other direction as well. I mean converting a nullable double to a nullable decimal.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want o convert from any data type to the other as long as they are compatible, use this:

```
    Convert.ChangeType(your variable, typeof(datatype you want convert to));
```

for example:

```
    string str= "123";
    int value1 = (int)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(int));
    float? value2 = (float?)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(float));
    ...................................
```

A little bit further, if you want it to be more safer, you can add a try catch on it:

```
string str= "123";
try
{
    int value1 = (int)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(int));
    int? value2 = (int?)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(int));
    float value3 = (float)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(float));
    float? value4 = (float?)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(float));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  // do nothing, or assign a default value
}
```

this is tested under VS 2010

Comment: Yes, this is a more general way to convert between types, not as succinct as the accepted answer. @Giswin Does it works for nullables as well? I imagine so, but I don't find a specific comment on this in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx).

Comment: you can use this:
decimal? v1 =222;
double? V2 = (double?)Convert.ChangeType(v1, typeof(double));
but if v1 is null, Convert.ChangeType will throw a exception. and then the try catch dose the left job.