# Convert to Nullable Decimal in Expression Trees

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, nullable

My models have Nullable decimal types. So in my Expression trees it gave me the following error:

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]' and 'System.Decimal'

Now I want to convert a string to decimal? and for that matter I have tried as:

```
decimal? res = Convert.ToDecimal(mystr); // this gives me type as System.Decimal
```

I have also looked to the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527453/cast-object-to-decimal-nullable-decimal), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347727/convert-decimal-to-double) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc). They all convert it into type System.Decimal and my expression trees gave the error mentioned above.

I really need to convert them to System.Nullable(System.Decimal) to work for me.

How can I work it out? My models are generated from Entity Framework EDMX so I cannot change their types. I have to do the conversion in the code.

Comment: You have converted it already. `res` is a nullable decimal.

Comment: it isn't.. when i checked as var d = res.GetType(); it gave me System.Decimal. and Expression tree also gave the same error

Comment: @AwaisMahmood: No, the type of `res` is `decimal?`. However, when you call `GetType()` it's boxing that to `decimal`... that's the way boxing works with nullable value types. The expression tree problem is pretty different.

Comment: thanks for explaining..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal C# code example you've shown *has* converted to `decimal?`, using the implicit conversion from `T` to `T?` for any non-nullable value type `T`.

In an expression tree, you just need to use `Expression.Convert` to perform that conversion, e.g.

```
// Assuming beforeConversion is an expression tree with a type of
// decimal
var converted = Expression.Convert(beforeConversion, typeof(decimal?));
```