# Convert array from nullable type to non-nullable of same type?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, types, nullable

I would like to convert a `Nullable(Of Byte)()` array (a.k.a. `byte?[]`) to a non-nullable array of the same type, that is, from `byte?[]` to `byte[]`.

I'm looking for the simpler, easier, faster generic solution, in C# or VB.NET. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487812/1248295) generic function to convert between nullable types but I can't find a way to adapt the conversion logic to convert from a nullable type to a non-nullable type.

This is a code example for which I feel the need to perform that kind of conversion:

```
byte?[] data = {1, 0, 18, 22, 255};
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", ", ");
```

Comment: `byte[] data2 = data.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();`

Comment: I didn't noted the LINQ approach, thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To convert an array of one type to an array of another type, use the [Array.ConvertAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
byte?[] data = { 1, 0, 18, 22, 255 };
byte[] result = Array.ConvertAll(data, x => x ?? 0);
```

This is simpler, easier, and faster than using LINQ.

Answer (score 6):

This method has to make an assumption of how to handle a null value. For this solution it is mapped to `default(byte) = 0` in order to have input and output to be of the same length.

```
byte?[] data = {1, 0, 18, 22, 255, null};
var byteArray = data.Select(
                 b => b ?? default(byte)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Found this looking thread for a way myself. I ended up using [`.OfType(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) to filter on type.

```
int?[] data = { 1, null, 18, 22, 255 };
var result = data.OfType<int>();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result)); // 1,18,22,255
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will return an array of non nullables.

```
 Dim arr() As Nullable(Of Byte)
 dim nonNullableArray = arr.Select(Function(item) item.Value).ToArray()
```

Comment: What if the item is null?