# Convert IEnumerable<T?> to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#

I'm looking to be able to take a list of nullable types T?, and remove any null values, leaving a type of T. For instance:

```cs
        List<int?> xs = new List<int?>() {1, 2, 3};
        
        // this method works
        IEnumerable<int> xs2 = xs.Select(x => x ?? 0);
        
        // this method does not
        IEnumerable<int> xs3 = xs.Where(x => x != null);
```

I appreciate C# isn't able to infer the type of the list such that it would be able to tell that there are no nulls in the list. But I'm struggling to find the best way to do this without just doing an explicit cast as in:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> xs3 = xs.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => (int)x);
```

The problem I have with this is that, if the `Where` statement wasn't there, then the code would still pass the type check, but would have a runtime error. Is there a way to do this in C# such that, at compile time, I can guarantee the type of the list is not nullable, and that it contains no nulls?

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z9vsCC)

I'd ideally like to do this in a generic way (but I have a separate problem there).

I managed to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310404/convert-array-from-nullable-type-to-non-nullable-of-same-type) which provides a good way of converting the values by converting nulls to a value of the type.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The canonical way to do this is `.Cast<int>()` (or `.Cast<T>()` in the general case). However, this is just syntactic sugar for your `Select`, so I'm not sure if you count that as an answer.

Comment: A simple `xs.OfType<int>();`?

Comment: @Ralf Yes! Solves it perfectly, I did not know that existed

Comment: @Heinzi `.Cast<int>()` will throw if it encounters a `null`.  Sometimes that's exactly what you want but it would change the behavior here

Comment: @AluanHaddad: I meant `Cast` as a replacement for `Select`, i.e. `.Where(x => x != null).Cast<int>()`. Ralf is perfectly right, of course, that `OfType` is even more concise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value):

```
IEnumerable<int> xs3 = xs.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I believe that `OfType` offers a better solution in this case, as it seems selecting with `Value` would still have a runtime exception on a null (appreciate in the example I'm filtering the nulls out already, really I like `OfType` because it doesn't rely on nulls having already been filtered coincidentally)

Comment: Because of the `x != null` filter before it, the `.Value` is guaranteed to succeed. Instead of `x != null` you can also do `Where(x => x.HasValue)`, this does exactly the same for a `Nullable<T>` and makes it a bit more obvious that you are dealing with a `Nullable<T>`. See the page that I linked to for more info.

Comment: My personal preference when dealing with nullables is use the .HasValue and .Value properties.

Comment: @PeterB Absolutely - my preference though is for the solution which doesn't rely on the code having already filtered out the nulls. Might be that I need to reword the question.

Comment: @C.M. This is a fine approach, but it's the same as the other question I referenced, I believe? You'd need to provide a fallback value x such that you end up with `IEnumerable<T | x>`? Totally fine I'm sure but I'm looking to filter them out.

Comment: I didn't know about this behavior of `OfType<>()`, seems odd at first sight, but useful at times.

Comment: @OliverRadini If you want a fallback value you use .GetValueOrDefault() which returns 0 for nullable ints. I thought you were filtering nulls out though.